# Keep it on the same page if there isn't any file to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I want to return a XML to user when it selects an order in a `SELECT`.

This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ProductionOrder>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("GetXML", "Orders"))
        {
            <p>
                @Html.DropDownList("productionOrderId", 
                                    new SelectList(Model, "Id", "OrderNumber"),
                                    "Orders",
                                    new {id = "OrdersSelect", onchange = "submit();"})
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `GetXML` method is this:

```
public FileContentResult GetXML(long productionOrderId)
{
    ProductionOrderReport poReport = null;

    poReport = new ProductionOrderReport(m_Repository, m_AggRepo, m_AggChildsRepo);

    // Get the XML document for this Production Order.
    XDocument doc = poReport.GenerateXMLReport(productionOrderId);

    if (doc != null)
    {
        // Convert it to string.
        StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter();
        doc.Save(writer, SaveOptions.None);

        // Convert the string to bytes.
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());

        return File(bytes, "application/xml", "report.xml");
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Sometimes the XML file returned can be null, and on those cases I get a empty screen on my browser.

How can I do to keep it the same page if the file is null?

I have tested this: instead of return null on `GetXML` method, I want to return a View (`Index.cshtml`), but I can't because `GetXML` returns `FileContentResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application permits to do the following changes, you can try the following:

```
public ActionResult GetXML(long productionOrderId) //Changed Return Type
{
    ProductionOrderReport poReport = null;

    poReport = new ProductionOrderReport(m_Repository, m_AggRepo, m_AggChildsRepo);

    // Get the XML document for this Production Order.
    XDocument doc = poReport.GenerateXMLReport(productionOrderId);

    if (doc != null)
    {
        // Convert it to string.
        StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter();
        doc.Save(writer, SaveOptions.None);

        // Convert the string to bytes.
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());

        return File(bytes, "application/xml", "report.xml");
    }
    else
        return RedirectToAction("ViewName","ControllerName"); //Instead of returning null, you can redirect back to the GET action of the original view.
}
```

Hope this help you.